# Is there a way to upload large files to github

Tags: django

I am trying to upload my Django application to Github so that I can deploy it to  Heroku. However, the files are prohibitively large.

I used lfs but even after compression, the upload gets stuck at 99% and  later on exhibits a fatal error.

I am using Postgres as my database.  I have video files that are about 400mb each in size.My static files are about 300mb each.

How do I fix this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Don't upload videos on Github. Upload videos on media server which served by NGINX or Apache. 
If you have static files in large size then upload one by one instead of bulk.